# Github HTML page run

Tags: github

I am new in GitHub. I am trying to run HTML page using GitHub. My Project name is **Ecommerce** and my Id is **manik452** . In my project i just use one file **index.html** . to run this i used bellow link **https://manik452.github.io/Ecommerce** but i cannot see my page but 404

There isn't a GitHub Pages site here.

Help me please if someone know about that

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't access the `index.html` like that, some steps should be taken, have a look: [Build A Static Website With Jekyll And GitHub Pages](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/08/build-blog-jekyll-github-pages/).

May it help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a branch called gh-pages then make your index.html
See the tutorial: https://pages.github.com/